# web browser stopped opening on project run

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, settings, cassini

This problem started ocurring after I had installed Visual Studio 2011 beta.
Either I run my asp.net site with or without debugging, browser doesn't open anymore.
Web server starts working(asp.net development server and/or IIS Express) but no browser is opened automatically when I click the link [localhost:myport] from web server's context menu.

Any suggestions what the problem could be?

[UPDATE]
Also links in "MS Outlook" and "MS Word" stopped working.

[UPDATE2]
Fortunatelly the fix was found:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823301

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem, F5 to start the Asp.Net app it compiles and runs but **doesn't launch a web browser**!

I narrowed it down to this setting in the config, removing this section from the appSettings.json allowed the app to use the launchSettings.json.

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
  }
```